# Why jQuery Cookie Plugin is not working on a particular page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using jQuery Cookie Plugin and its working fine on all pages except on home page for running that page I am banging my head but no luck.

My code looks like:

```
$.cookie('CA_txtKeywords', $("#CAT_txtKeywords").val(), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

In firebug It says:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'

Can some one please guide what is this error and how to remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You include jQuery in your head, then you include the cookie plugin, but then at the bottom of the page you have this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
  // (e.g. 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today and 1 would load 1.4.1).
  google.load("jquery", "1");

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
$(".euro").parseNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"it"});
$(".euro").formatNumber({format:"#,###", locale:"it"});

})
</script>
```

Which loads jQuery AGAIN using the google loader. Because you load jQuery again, whatever was attached directly to the jQuery namespace (not the prototype) in the head of the document gets removed.

So it comes down to, why in the world are you loading jQuery twice?

Solution:

Remove the google loader and request for it to load jQuery from the footer of your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Plugin is loaded on your homepage? Have you looked into the source?
You can check the loaded scripts in your firebug aswell.

Comment: Yes I checked and plugin is loaded on my home page you can see yourself... 
http://www.unicaimmobili.com/index_copy